# choose accessdatabase in loginscreen, then login with creds from table

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, authentication

I'm trying to make a login screen with following properties:
Left pane: button to choose an access database (open file).
as soon as the "connect" button is pressed, the right pane opens with a user/password screen.
The user and password should be checked in the access database users table.
The database is only loaded if correct credentials from inside the file are provided.

So in short:
Is this possible or do i need a separate file to store those credentials and how to load the database in order to access it in my software.
I'm a beginner.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is you must open the database in order read the credentials. Therefore you need two layers of security.

The good news is MS Access supports this. You can [set a password on the database file itself](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/encrypt-a-database-by-using-a-database-password-12aa0e5c-34c6-4957-af3b-b5f5cfa9a766), and then distribute that password with your app in a place where the user can't see.

The bad news is these passwords aren't all that secure. First, securely distributing a credential with your app so it can't be discovered is surprising difficult. In short, it's something you should *not* be attempting as a beginner. Second, the MS Access password protection feature is [not all that strong](https://www.google.com/search?q=recover%20ms%20access%20database%20password).

Most systems where security really matters will keep the credentials and most important data on a system they control, usually via a web service.

If you do proceed with the Access database, make sure you understand the correct way to store user passwords... namely that you *don't **ever*** store the password itself, but instead only keep a cryptographic hash. When a user logs in, you also hash the attempted password and then compare the hashes.

Comment: In regards to setting a database password, see [the following](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/WorkingWithAccessDatabases#encryption-notes) about some gotchas.

Comment: @Karen You don't want to check the _use legacy encryption_ box if you want secure encryption. Joel, Access password protection is plenty strong if you make sure you don't use user-level security nor legacy encryption. Most recovery options rely on legacy encryption, the ones that don't either brute-force or dictionary attack it, so with a long non-dictionary password + modern encryption you're fine (except the standard limitations of encryption apply, you only have a single password + no rights management).